# Max frequency of a component?

Tags: microcontroller, power, transistors, frequency, scr

For example, an SCR, is this the maximum frequency you can send a 'on' or 'off' signal from an Arduino to it, or is it the maximum frequency of say, 30V flowing through it?

Please let me know, I don't want to accidentally ruin all my parts.

Comment: Datasheet says?

Comment: That's not an answer, the data sheets do not specify a port of interfacing for the frequency. "Is the max frequency a limitation on the switching input or the component output?" Is more specific, but I shouldn't have to phrase it that obviously for you to realize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCRs turn on and then stay on until the current through them drops to zero (perhaps because they're switching AC). They're typically used at mains frequency up to a few kHz and not above.

Here are some switching characteristics from an inexpensive 8A SCR (the [BT151-500R](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BT151-500RT.pdf))

[image]

The dVd/dt is a maximum rating

tgt and tq are typical turn-on and turn-off times under specific conditions.

It is quite unlikely you'll damage an SCR through switching the gate at too high a frequency- more likely it just won't do what you want.

MOSFETs are bit trickier- if you try to drive the gate faster than your driver can handle it can cause the MOSFET to overheat because it spends too much time between full-on and full-off so the load current causes the MOSFET to overheat. SCRs latch on, so that isn't so much of an issue.

Comment: So what if I switched it a single time, to turn it on, and then put 115V 150kHz through the SCR? That's not switching it at higher than 1kHz so the dv/dt is fine on the gate, but there should be a maximum for the dv/dt on the terminals themselves, no?

Comment: There's not enough time for it to commutate (turn off) so it will just stay on forever (or until the 150kHz goes away). It needs 70us and a 150kHz sine only spends ~3us in each polarity.

Comment: Hm, so then the solution would be some sort of MOSFET setup for the necessary speed? I was thinking TRIACs but those are just two SCRs so, shit.

Comment: Probably. If you have some specific situation in mind you can post a related question. Switching a MOSFET on and off at 150kHz probably requires a driver circuit, 1kHz probably not, but the details are going to be heavily dependent on the actual task. BJTs are useful too. Think of triacs and SCRs as mostly useful for switching mains AC 50/60Hz and you won't go far wrong.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Well see it's that same problem of me simply just wanting to turn the path on once and let the 150kHz oscillate through the MOSFETs, not actually switching it at the gate. Is that possible? So far it seems that a bootstrap driver is necessary, and that means I'll have to switch the MOSFET switch rapidly to charge it anyway.